# how to Send Text Messages (SMS) From Android When Near A Predefined Location

Tags: android, android-location

Send Text Messages (SMS) From Android When Near A Predefined Location...

Ex. i enter in the college or out from the college that time my Android device check my current position if it match with predefine position then my device send automatic sms to other no.

Any buddy have idea or code related to this ..

thank you..

Comment: if any buddy have code related to this please send it to me on my id prashant.kadam4995@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put whole code from my SMS util. You should have a look at  *sendSms* function. The util allows you to watch for incoming sms and track sms sent by you ( If you want to do that ).

The next part is to handle location updates. The best way how to do it depends on many things. You can obtain location via LocatinProviders ( GPS, wireless or passive ) or read cell info from TelephonyManager. Below you have some details about them:

1. LocationProvider:

   - returns geo lat/lon data
   - you can not read data if user disabled "Use GPS satellites" and "User wireless networks"
   - you will rather not get data if you are in a building ( no GPS signal there ).
   - you have to wait very long for the location.
   - very good accuracy.
   - can drain battery a lot.
   - "[pasive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER)" provider can be a good choice for you.
2. Cells.

   - returns the neighboring cell information of the device.
   - location is not available if your device is not connected to gsm/cdma network ( no sim card ).
   - not good accuracy but rather for you purpose will be ok.
   - doesn't kill battery so much.

Which option is better for you ?

```
   package android.commons;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
    import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
    import android.util.Log;

    public final class SmsModem extends BroadcastReceiver {

            private static final String SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_ACTION = "android.commons.SMS_DELIVER_REPORT";
            private static final String SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_TOKEN_EXTRA = "token";

            private static final String TAG = SmsModem.class.getSimpleName();
            private final Context context;
            private final SmsManager smsManager;
            private final SmsModemListener listener;

            private final Map<String, Integer> pendingSMS = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public interface SmsModemListener {
                    public void onSMSSent(String token);
                    public void onSMSSendError(String token, String errorDetails);
                    public void onNewSMS(String address, String message);
            }

            public SmsModem(Context c, SmsModemListener l) {
                    context = c;
                    listener = l;
                    smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction(SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_ACTION);
                    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                    context.registerReceiver(this, filter);         
            }

            public void sendSms(String address, String message, String token) {             
                    if ( message != null && address != null && token != null) {
                            final ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);                      
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra(SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_TOKEN_EXTRA, token);                                         
                            final PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            final ArrayList<PendingIntent> intents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                            for ( int i = 0 ; i < parts.size() ; i++ ) {
                                    intents.add(sentIntent);
                            }
                            pendingSMS.put(token, parts.size());
                            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, parts, intents, null);
                    }       
            }

            public void clear() {
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                    final String action = intent.getAction();
                    if ( action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
                if (bundle != null) { 
                        Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
                        for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) { 
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                            final String address = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                            final String message = messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody();
                            listener.onNewSMS(address, message);
                        } 
                    }
                    } else if ( action.equalsIgnoreCase(SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_ACTION)) {
                            final int resultCode = getResultCode();
                            final String token = intent.getStringExtra(SMS_DELIVER_REPORT_TOKEN_EXTRA);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Deliver report, result code '" + resultCode + "', token '" + token + "'");
                            if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                                    if ( pendingSMS.containsKey(token) ) {
                                            pendingSMS.put(token, pendingSMS.get(token).intValue() - 1);
                                            if ( pendingSMS.get(token).intValue() == 0 ) {
                                                    pendingSMS.remove(token);
                                                    listener.onSMSSent(token);
                                            }
                                    }                               
                            } else {
                                    if ( pendingSMS.containsKey(token) ) {
                                            pendingSMS.remove(token);
                                            listener.onSMSSendError(token, extractError(resultCode, intent));                                       
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

            private String extractError(int resultCode, Intent i) {
                    switch ( resultCode ) {
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            if ( i.hasExtra("errorCode") ) {
                                    return i.getStringExtra("errorCode");
                            } else {
                                    return "Unknown error. No 'errorCode' field.";
                            }
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            return "No service";                    
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            return "Radio off";
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            return "PDU null";
                            default:
                                    return "really unknown error";
                    }
            }
    }
```